# Red5 streaming problems with MP4

Tags: video, video-streaming, mp4, red5, metafile

I am using Red5 to stream my videos. But the buffer is getting null for MP4 videos. There is no problem with flv videos. And for some MP4 files its streaming correctly. But only few MP4 files are not streaming properly. I looked about MOOV ATOM issue. And, changed it to front to allow progressive download. But Either the ways its not working. Any help?
Reasons may be:
1) Red5 is not generating meta file for MP4.

For flv its Red5 creating metafiles automatically. Is this the main cause? If so, how to fix/generate metafile for MP4 files automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
That is because of missing metadata in mp4 file. So, originally I converted wmv file to mp4 file and trying to stream that. So, the software I used misses the metadata. Now, I converted the same wmv file using different converter (AVC), and now there is no problem. Its streaming properly. I hope, this will help somebody.